# Ошибка при использовании selector с vector drawables

Tags: android, xml

Есть такой selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_like_selected_24dp" 
          android:state_selected="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_like_24dp" 
          android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

На устройстве c android 4.3

Возникает ошибка:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
```

Сам ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/likeBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/like_selector" />
```

### ic_like_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF0000"
    android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
```

### ic_like__selected_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF0000"
    android:pathData="M12,21.35l-1.45,-1.32C5.4,15.36 2,12.28 2,8.5 2,5.42 4.42,3 7.5,3c1.74,0 3.41,0.81 4.5,2.09C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3 19.58,3 22,5.42 22,8.5c0,3.78 -3.4,6.86 -8.55,11.54L12,21.35z"/>
```

Comment: попробуйте еще задать <item> по умолчанию. ну и скиньте сам xml вашей ImageView

Comment: @SviatVolkov не помогло

Comment: а стоп, точно. туплю. в андроиде векторы завезли только с 5го андроида. на версиях старше можете использовать только картиночки

Comment: возможно вы работаете не через support библиотеку

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution гайд по совместимости. пробуйте. если сработает оформлю ответом

Comment: @SviatVolkov в gradle я это прописал vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: интересно то что если, использовать векторы без selector, то все работает

Answer (score 0):

Селектор прописывается в `background`

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/likeBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/like_selector" />
```

А также, думаю, что для картинки нужно прописать свойства:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: попробовал, не помогло